# OnbackPrees to return home always in react stack navigation

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation-stack

I am do do navigation in react native where all the back arrow or back press return to initial route. On last on option is to list to onBackPreessed event and passs call to init route which is home.
I am hoping their will be props for allowing the Screen to return to init   Screen in stack navigations

**What is happening**

On **home**:
go **details** then go **A**
back arrow press in **A**, it  return  back to  **details**

**Need actions**

On **home**:
go **details** then go **A**
back arrow press in **A**  return  back to **home** instead of **details**

*The code I try*

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Button, View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';

function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Home Screen</Text>
      <Button
        title="Go to Details"
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Details')}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

function DetailsScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Details Screen</Text>
      <Button
        title="Go to A"
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('A')}
      />

    </View>
  );
}
function A({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text>AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA Screen</Text>


    </View>
  );
}
const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home" detachInactiveScreens={true}
        detachPreviousScreen={true}>
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />

        <Stack.Group screenOptions={{ presentation: 'modal' }}>
          <Stack.Screen name="Details" component={DetailsScreen}
            options={{ presentation: 'transparentModal' }}
          />
          <Stack.Screen name="A" component={A} />
        </Stack.Group>
      </Stack.Navigator>


    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

u can do it by passing "key" to "navigate"
more info (source):
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-prop/

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-prop/#going-back-from-a-specific-screen

```js
navigation.navigate({ name: SCREEN, key: SCREEN_KEY_A });
navigation.navigate({ name: SCREEN, key: SCREEN_KEY_B });
navigation.navigate({ name: SCREEN, key: SCREEN_KEY_C });
navigation.navigate({ name: SCREEN, key: SCREEN_KEY_D });
```

```js
navigation.navigate({ key: SCREEN_KEY_A }); // will go to screen A FROM screen D
```

Comment: the problem is that i don't want to keep back stack such onbackpress  or back arrow in stack navigator will always take it home

Comment: yea read link that i posted, it says all other screens will be POPed ( pop ) removed from stack

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use **BackHandler** on Screen A.

So you should listen for BackHandler in Screen A and the navigate to Home screen when it's triggered.

Your Screen A should look like this:

```
  import { BackHandler } from 'react-native';

  function handleBackPressHandler() {
    navigation.navigate('HomeScreen');
    return true;
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', handleBackPressHandler);

    return () => {
      BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', handleBackPressHandler);
    };
  }, []);
```

Comment: Thanks for reply.  It  fails to work........ I think reason is I am using arrow on stack navigator.  And don't know but the event will certainty not be 'hardwareBackPress '.  using the arrow... running on web

Answer (score 0):

The default behaviour of React Navigation is this only, it takes you to the last visited stack on pressing back but if you want to update it, you can you this line of code:

```
useFocusEffect( //imported from @react-navigation/native-stack
React.useCallback(() => {
  const onBackPress = () => {
    navigation.navigate('InitialRouteName');
  };

  BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', onBackPress);

  return () =>
    BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', onBackPress);
}, [])
```

);

For reference, you can check this out - https://reactnavigation.org/docs/custom-android-back-button-handling/

Comment: Thanks for your reply  I got this error                                     (0 , _nativeStack.useFocusEffect) is not a function

Comment: sorry, you have to import it from @react-navigation/native instead of native-stack. It will look something like this - import { useFocusEffect } from '@react-navigation/native';

Answer (score 0):

please try this,

import { BackHandler } from 'react-native';

<!- -->

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const backAction = () => {
      navigation.navigate('intialRouteName');
      return true;
    };

    const backHandler = BackHandler.addEventListener(
      'hardwareBackPress',
      backAction,
    );

    return () => backHandler.remove();
  }, []);
```